# writting dict to json file in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a text file in which I have data in the below format in one pkt.

```
{"pkt":{"Seq":6850,"Person":"ABCD1","inf0":[-1,0,6,8,3,-1,0,7,8,3,-2],"inf1":[49,95,-12,-115,-63,62,88],"Accel":[6,0,728,224,-8192,224,-8192,0,-8192,0,200,0,200,31762,200,30738,4758,31506,4779,-26153,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"breath":[2104015,2103950,2103707,2103330],"TsSpO2":1712431500,"vBat":3062,"rf_gain":0,"Temp":-32768,"bhtgg":1712500736}}
```

below is the code.

```
f1 = open('ecg.txt')
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    for line in f1:
        json.dump(ast.literal_eval(line),fp)
```

this does create the file however that file doesn't open. It gives the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
**kw)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 1356 - line 1 column 38753099 (char 1355 - 38753098)
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. You have to parse the input. Then you can write that to some other format. You cannot just "convert text to json" because that does not mean anything.

Comment: Also the contents of the file you have posted here are not correct in syntax. In `inf1`, the last value is just a `-` and the `breath` doesn't start with an open bracket `[`.

Comment: basically i was trying to read the dict to write onto a json file. will correct it.

Comment: your text file contains valid JSON, you can create a copy of your file and rename it to `jsonfile.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Read your text file in `r` or read mode, read it and convert it into dict using the `ast.literal_eval`. Use `json.dump` since we have an object and dump it into another file opened in `w` or write mode.

```
f1 = open('ecg.txt', r)
json.dump(ast.literal_eval(f1.read()),open('jsonfile.json', 'w)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.